# New SQLite layer will not save in QGIS

Tags: qgis, sqlite

I have previously drawn and added a SQLite line feature to a map with no problems. I get the attached message when I try to save it.  I can add and save as a shapefile but prefer to have only the one file. I was using Madeira before but using Coruna now in case that has any bearing on the problem.

[image]

Error message:

> Could not commit changes to layer derf
>
> Errors: ERROR: 1 feature(s) not added.
> Provider errors:
> SQLite error: unknown cause
> SQL: INSERT INTO "derf"("geometry",,"line") VALUES (GeomFromWKB(?, 4326),,?)

Have tried on Surface book with Madeira and it still works OK there.

Comment: Please post error messages as text in the body of the question. Images are not legible on all devices and cannot be indexed by search engines.